# System.Diagnostics.Process - Del Command

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I'm trying to start the del command using System.Diagnostic.Process.  Basically I want to delete everything from the C:\ drive that has the filename of *.bat

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
string args = string.Empty;
args += "*.bat";

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "del";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args.TrimEnd();
proc.Start();
```

However when code is ran an exception is thrown, "the system cannot find specified file."  I know there definitely is files in that root folder containing that file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to start a del command. You can delete files from C#.

```
        var files = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\").GetFiles("*.bat");
        foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
```

Comment: I was using io and some other methods but had issues with UAC and permissions outside the user profile.

If I changed the manifest to execute as administrator then it wouldn't properly detect the currently logged in user for tasks I needed to perform.

Answer (score 9):

"del" is not an executable.  It's a command run by the command interpreter, cmd.exe.  Instead of running "del", run `cmd.exe /c "del foo.txt"`.

Comment: Interesting, I'll bear this in mind for other console commands if I can't find the .Net functionality.

Comment: cmd.exe /c is also useful for those times when you want to run a batch file from the Process class.

Answer (score 0):

`del` is a console command, not an application that can be started through the `Process` class. Is there a reason you're going at it this way instead of using the managed classes in the `System.IO` namespace?